# delay in transition android

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

am using this  transition the problem is after closing the app the transition image remain for 2 s any idea how can i fix it to not delay  .

```
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this,Login.class);


            ActivityOptions options = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        Start.this,logo, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(logo));
            }
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(Start.this,intent,options.toBundle());
            mShouldFinish = true;
        }
    }, timeOut);
```